# unlist and merge selected columns to data frame in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list such like:

```
df1<-data.frame(n=letters[1:4], x=1:4, y=2:5, z=3:6)
df2<-data.frame(n=letters[2:5], x=2:5, y=3:6, z=4:7)
df3<-data.frame(n=letters[3:7], x=2:6, y=3:7, z=4:8)
ls<-list(df1, df2, df3)
ls
[[1]]
  n x y z
1 a 1 2 3
2 b 2 3 4
3 c 3 4 5
4 d 4 5 6

[[2]]
  n x y z
1 b 2 3 4
2 c 3 4 5
3 d 4 5 6
4 e 5 6 7

[[3]]
  n x y z
1 c 2 3 4
2 d 3 4 5
3 e 4 5 6
4 f 5 6 7
5 g 6 7 8
```

what I wanted is to merger the first two columns of each data frame in the list by column `n` and a desired output would be:

```
  n x1 x2  x3
1 a   1  NA NA
2 b   2   2 NA
3 c   3   3  2
4 d   4   4  3
5 e  NA   5  4
6 f  NA  NA  5
7 g  NA  NA  6
```

And same thing for y and z:

```
  n   y1 y2  y3
1 a   2  NA NA
2 b   3   3 NA
3 c   4   4  3
4 d   5   5  4
5 e  NA   6  5
6 f  NA  NA  6
7 g  NA  NA  7

  n  z1  z2 z3
1 a   3  NA NA
2 b   4   4 NA
3 c   5   5  4
4 d   6   6  5
5 e  NA   7  6
6 f  NA  NA  7
7 g  NA  NA  8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We get the `unique` column names from the `list` of `data.frame`s except the 'n' ('nm1'), loop through those (`lapply(nm1,...`), subset the columns of each of the 'data.frame' in 'ls' (`lapply(ls, function(x) ...`), and use `Reduce`, with `merge` to merge the datasets in the `list`.

```
nm1 <- setdiff(unlist(lapply(ls, names)), "n")
lapply(nm1, function(nm)  setNames(Reduce(function(...)
    merge(..., all=TRUE, by = "n"), lapply(ls, 
                 function(x) x[c("n", nm)])), make.unique(c("n", rep(nm, length(nm1))))))
#[[1]]
#  n  x x.1 x.2
#1 a  1  NA  NA
#2 b  2   2  NA
#3 c  3   3   2
#4 d  4   4   3
#5 e NA   5   4
#6 f NA  NA   5
#7 g NA  NA   6

#[[2]]
#  n  y y.1 y.2
#1 a  2  NA  NA
#2 b  3   3  NA
#3 c  4   4   3
#4 d  5   5   4
#5 e NA   6   5
#6 f NA  NA   6
#7 g NA  NA   7

#[[3]]
#  n  z z.1 z.2
#1 a  3  NA  NA
#2 b  4   4  NA
#3 c  5   5   4
#4 d  6   6   5
#5 e NA   7   6
#6 f NA  NA   7
#7 g NA  NA   8
```

NOTE: `ls` is a function name that lists the objects. It is better to avoid naming objects with known `R` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R method that uses `do.call`, `data.frame`, and `cbind` within a nested pair of `lapply` functions.

```
# get all levels of n across data frames
allN <- unique(unlist(sapply(ls, "[[", "n")))
# extract desired columns and provide names with setNames
lapply(names(ls[[1]])[-1], function(var) {
       cbind("n"=allN, setNames(do.call(data.frame,
         lapply(seq_along(ls), function(i) {
                                 ls[[i]][[var]][match(allN, ls[[i]]$n, nomatch=NA)]
                               })), paste0(var, seq_along(ls))))
})
```

The first `lapply` runs through each of the variable names, the second `lapply` extracts the current variable from the each data frame in the list. In the middle, `do.call` makes the list a data.frame, `setNames` provides the desired names, and the n column is added with `cbind`.

In the innermost portion of the inner `lapply`, the code `ls[[i]][[var]][match(allN, ls[[i]]$n, nomatch=NA)]` is used to expand (and potentially reorder) the current vector according to the levels in allN. If the current vector is missing a level, the nomatch=NA tells `match` to instead return `NA`.